# Jquery how to change text value of div with an effect

Tags: jquery, html, effect

I am able to change inside of div with the following code

```
$(".mydivclass").html("my data");
```

Now if possible i want to add an effect like show (delay) or something other. How can i do that when changing the data inside div. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little simple example using fading effect.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sometext">
    Start text 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#sometext").fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).text("change!").fadeIn();
});
```

Fiddle on : http://jsfiddle.net/uxhE2/

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution Irvin. Working quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you need to do is `chaining` different jquery methods. E.g. this would be a simple hide and show effect.

```
$(".mydivclass").hide().html("my data").show('slow');
```

If you prefer some hiding effect, which is time based, you need to define your "show" effect inside a `callback`, like PeeHaa illustrated. Otherwise the effects won't be "queued" and the show effect will start before the hiding has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an element dynamically and made the content fade in

```
$("<span id='myData'>my data</span>").hide().appendTo(".mydivclass");
$("#myData").fadeIn()
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/MqhdG/

Answer (score 1):

Because you say any effect what about:

```
$(".mydivclass").slideUp('slow', function() {
  $(".mydivclass").html('data');
  $(".mydivclass").slideDown('slow');
});
```