# var change detect in html by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, clock

I have a clock script and everything is fine, but I want to detect when the minutes change and add to this action some animation with jQuery, for example fadeToggle.

Can you tell me how can I detect the time change?

This is my script:

```
window.setInterval(function updateClock() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    $.ajax({
        success:function (clock) {
            document.getElementById("hour").firstChild.nodeValue = currentHours;
            document.getElementById("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = currentMinutes;
        }
    });
    if (currentMinutes.length == 1) {
        currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: You're setting the minutes in your function? You know when it changes -- just do what ever else you need at that point...

Comment: Not what's being asked, but if you want to create a good animated transaction you need an additional div and some css, unless you want to look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8202162/1386111) (I personally think it's not good)